# GWT TextBox value change handler

Tags: gwt, textbox

i have a `TextBox` which is used for searching products in my app. This `TextBox` should do searching after user key in keywords to the `TextBox` or when user hits `ENTER`.

to be able to explain further, this `TextBox` worked like the `Google's` search box wherein search results are viewed instantly after user input.

i have tried the `ValueChangeHandler` but the event will only fired if the `TextBox` loses its focus. i also tried `KeyPressEventHandler` but i want to only fire the search event after user key-in the keyword, not on every key press. can anyone give me an idea on how to do this?

i was thinking of using the `GWT` `Timer` to fire the search event after a certain time. the timer would only run if user no longer key-in keys to the `TextBox` but how will i know if no `KeyPressEvent` is fired?

Comment: Did you consider using GWT's SuggestBox? you will have to modify it to match your needs but it is closer to what you describe than TextBox

Answer (score 2):

This works for me :

```
@UiHandler("searchBox")
public void onKeyUpEvent(KeyUpEvent keyPress) {
   // do the search
}
```

You need KeyUpEvent, KeyPressEventHandler will always be late...

Answer (score 0):

Use KeyPressEventHandler or KeyUpEventHandler and check whether the last typed character equals a whitespace. I think you can receive the key, which fired the event, from the event object. Otherwise use the getText() methode of the TextBox. Do only update the search results when you detect a whitespace or ENTER. I know this doen't solve the problem if the user stops typing after a word :-)

Answer (score 0):

I checked in the handler code of the pressed key, and depending on it to perform some action.

```
searchQueryTextBox.addKeyUpHandler(new KeyUpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onKeyUp(KeyUpEvent event) {
            if (event.getNativeKeyCode() == 13 || event.getNativeKeyCode() == 32) {
                //run a search. code 13 - key "Enter", code 32 - key "Space"
            } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: that would only search when you press enter, @july wants google instant search behaviour. further, the solution is the same.

Comment: I realized that @july wants to search began only when the word is full, and not after every key-click. Or when you press enter